# Php array _push not pushing another array push

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sorry guys for the silly question, but I am encountering an strange problem. The code used to work with php 5.2 but I have moved to 5.5 and it is not working.

Anyways I ma trying to retrieve data from database and pushing in an array. The query is displaying correct data but not working in array.
This is my code

```
$data = array();
$mm = array();
$m = array();
$y = array();
$years = array();
$f = array();
$facts = array();
$i = 0;
$g = array();
$groups = array();
$r = array();
$regions = array();
$import = array();
$imports = array();
$colcount = 0;
$sumunits=0;
$sumvalue=0;
$sumasp=0;



    while($d = mysql_fetch_array($getdata))
    { 

        if($i > 0)
            { 
                    array_push($mm, $month, $units, $value, $asp); 
                    $colcount++;
                    array_push($m, $mm);
                    $mm = array();

                    if($year != $d['data_year'] || $fact != $d['data_fact'] || $region != $d['data_region'] || $importtime != $d['importtime'])
                    {
                        array_push($y, $year, $m);   
                        array_push($years, $y);
                        $m = array();
                        $y = array();
                    }
                    if($fact != $d['data_fact'] || $group != $d['fact_group'] || $region != $d['data_region'] || $importtime != $d['importtime'])
                    { 
                        array_push($f, $factname, $years, $oldlabel, $order); 
                        array_push($facts, $f);
                        $f = array();
                        $years = array();
                        $colcount = 0;
                    }
            }

    $i++;
    }

array_push($mm, $month, $units, $value, $asp);
array_push($m, $mm);
if($year != $d['data_year'])
{
    array_push($y, $year, $m); 
    array_push($years, $y);
    $m = array();
    $y = array();
    $colcount++;
}
if($fact != $d['fact_id'])
{
    array_push($f, $factname, $years, $oldlabel, $order);
    array_push($facts, $f);
    $f = array();
    $years = array();
}
```

It was working with php 5.2 but not working on php 5.5, Please help me guys.

Thank you

Comment: are you sure the problem lies under `array_push` ? it shouldnt wont work just because of `array_push`

Comment: The query is showing correct data but when I print the array, it doesn't show all the results

Comment: @BharatPaudyal Nothing has changed between versions concerning `array_push`, it shouldn't influence your results. @Andrew well...this is strange.

Comment: Smartphone (Nov 2015) Units  (k)","data":[{"x":"Jan","y":"1284"},{"x":"Feb","y":"1075"},{"x":"Mar","y":"1092"},{"x":"Apr","y":"1035"},{"x":"May","y":"1220"},{"x":"Jun","y":"1166"},{"x":"Jul","y":"1308"},{"x":"Aug","y":"1266"},{"x":"Sep","y":"1227"},{"x":"Oct","y":"1293"},{"x":"Nov","y":"1287"},{"x":"Dec","y":"1372"}]. This is what I am getting but  should get for 3 years. I am just getting for one year (Nov 2015) But should also get (Sep 2015, Aug 2015 and June 2015 Data)

Comment: at one second, I am confused @Andrew's post because I didnt do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is your database connection.

MYSQL is deprecated as of php 5.5.0

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been
>   removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further
>   help while choosing a MySQL API.
>
> Link: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

It is better to use `PDO` or `MYSQLi` for security or maintainability

Comment: But other pages without array_push are working perfectly with mysql

Comment: Than thats is more strange, if you set this `error_reporting(E_ALL)` does it show any error?

Comment: @BharatPaudyal sorry im not an expert on this, but the new server should have everything you need..

Comment: It seems that I have done array_unique , which is not working properly
array_push($import, $importtime, $regions); 
 array_push($imports, $import);
 $regions = array();
 $import = array();
$imports = array_unique($imports);

Comment: $imports = array_unique($imports, SORT_REGULAR); Worked for me.

Comment: @BharatPaudyal glad you found the real problem :) meanwhile, please also consider my advice too regardless :)

Answer (score 1):

It was actually array_unique which was not working.
PHP 5.2 did sort by String, while later version use by default regular sorting.

$imports = array_unique($imports, SORT_REGULAR);

so sort_regular works for me :)
Thank you all for their comments